# Cypress installation fails with Proxy setup

Tags: angular, npm-install, cypress

I am trying to install cypress to my Angular 8 project.

But when I try to install, I am getting the same error over and over again.

[image]

I've added the proxy in my environment variables and also in my .npmrc file.
Those are the proxy variables I have found on the company's wiki.
But I'am still getting the same error.

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set up below environment variables before installing through command line.

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://domain%5Cusername:password@proxy:80
set HTTP_PROXY=http://domain%5Cusername:password@proxy:80
```

Also, set below proxy values for npm

```
npm config set proxy http://domain%5Cusername:password@proxy:80
npm config set http-proxy http://domain%5Cusername:password@proxy:80
```

Also, ensure you are using the correct url for the proxy server.

Cheers!

Comment: I already set the environment variables. I've cheched it.
The Url I've used for the proxy server is the correct one.

Comment: I also did this:

npm config set HTTPS_PROXY=http://[CompanyProxy]:8080

npm config set HTTPs_PROXY=http://[CompanyProxy]:8080

Of course, I changed [CompanyProxy] with the right value.

Comment: Your npm proxy variables doesn't seem to be correct. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue even after setting the proper proxy, I had to download the binary manually and set it during npm installation

```
CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=~/Downloads/cypress.zip npm install cypress --save-dev
```

Download the cypress.zip from the official website

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is setting the CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY variable to a local zip folder.

I know this will not work in Azure DevOps, but maybe the install works in the build pipeline.

This is something I have to test.

**Update**

The install works on Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue and finally found the solution. Assuming you have your Cypress repository cloned and there is a configured package.json file with your version of Cypress entered e.g. 9.5.0.  Download the Cypress Binary zip folder for your Cypress version from https://download.cypress.io e.g. 9.5.0.zip and copy it to %APPDATA%..\Local\Cypress\Cache.  Open a command prompt and change directory to your cypress repo.  Run npx install and it should install without the proxy issue.